How to suppress "Workload updates are available" message when running dotnet
I am seeing messages like this in my command line build for .NET projects when using dotnet.exe:
[project name]: Workload updates are available.  Run 'dotnet workload list' for more information.

I can run Visual Studio Installer to update and will no longer see the messages.  But each time there is an update, I will probably see these messages again.  Is there a way to suppress this message to clean up my build output?

This issue is similar to Suppress workload update notification from dotnet run reported by other user previously. Looks like the issue was fixed https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/pull/22573.  What is the version of your .NET SDK? I would suggest you  confirm at above link to see if the issue reappears.
As a workaround, to disable the daily SDK check for updates, try to set the DOTNET_CLI_WORKLOAD_UPDATE_NOTIFY_DISABLE environment variable to true.
For more information, please refer to .NET environment variables

That fix is for 'dotnet run' and does not apply to 'dotnet build'.  You can see from the code changes that 'build' and 'publish' set 'commandOptedOut' to 'false', while 'run' sets it to 'true'.

I am currently on 17.11.4 and the latest is 17.11.5.  Updating will make the message go away until the next update, but I am looking for a more permanent way to hide this message in our build output so it's easier to see important warnings.  Setting DOTNET_CLI_WORKLOAD_UPDATE_NOTIFY_DISABLE did not change anything in the build output.

Sorry for ignoring that fix is for dotnet run. Looks like this feature is by design. I am afraid there is no any available arguments/configurations to suppress it for now. I would suggest you report this issue at dotnet/sdk to get the issue fixed.

I logged an issue as suggested.
